# Instalador WindowsForm VS 2017 + SqlServer 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

anduve buscando en distintos foros, incluyendo éste, la pregunta es la siguiente, cual es la manera mas facil de realizar el instalador, estuve intentando con Advanced Installer, pero la verdad no puedo instalar el programa en otra pc ya que me arroja error, no se que pude haber hecho mal, de que otra manera pudieran recomendarme realizarlo??   desde mi pc funciona correctamente el instalador ya que tiene la cadena de conexion justamente para mi pc pero en otra es el problema, la idea es que en el instalador lleve todo los requisitos para que funcione el programa perfectamente como funciona en mi computadora, si alguien me pudiera dar una mano le agradeceria, ya me esta desesperando esto que hace dias que busco informacion y no puedo realizarlo.
gracias saludos

Comment: Asegurate que todos los recursos esten incluidos al publicar el .exe. NUNCA funcionario si en la cadena de conexion apunta a tu equipo eso es ilogico.

Comment: No creo que sea algo facil pero date una vuelta por este link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/7007a345-26f0-4626-9202-4c0106315797/cmo-aadir-una-base-de-datos-sqlserver-al-instalador-de-mi-aplicacin?forum=vcses

Comment: Si usas Sql Server deberas tener el servicio en algun lugar, ya sea en una pc que actue como Servidor de base de datos o en la pc local del usuario. Para esto deberas llevar junto a tu instalador de la aplicaicon el instalador del sql server, si es algo chico podrias llevar el Sql Server Express. Una vez instalador el sql serer deberas ejecutar un restor de una db que tengas o sino ejecutar los script de creacion de la db y las tablas

Comment: yo lo que hice fue seguir este tuto : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aN8ufyKAnGU, pero a la hora de instalar, luego de instalar el motor, continua con el programa y me arroja el error de que ya existe tal base de datos que esta queriendo crear el programa y me indica el nombre, mientras que en realidad no existe tal base de datos

Comment: leandro. a ver si te entiendo puedo instalar un sql express en la pc de prueba, llevaria los script de mi base de datos y los restauro en la base de datos de la pc de prueba?? y desde el instalador tendria que cambiar algo? el archivo donde esta la cadena de conexion??

Comment: Podria tratar la DB aparte, pero tendria que sacar el script y llevarlo al otro motor de la pc de prueba y restaurarlo desde ahi?

Comment: lo pude arreglar, muchas gracias